# CoreBluetooth : only discovering one peripheral whereas the native bluetooth feature discovers three

Tags: ios, macos, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I'm implementing an OS X app that uses bluetooth to connect to a Raspberry Pi.
The problem is that the app can't discover the RPI whereas I can see it on the Mac's native bluetooth panel.
The app only discovers one device that has a "null" name ( whereas every devices I can see on my Mac's bluetooth panel have a name ).

Any idea about what the problem could be ?

Here is the implementation of my Bluetooth manager singleton :

```
static let sharedInstance = KNKBluetoothManager()

var centralManager : CBCentralManager!
var remotePeripheral : CBPeripheral?
var bluetoothReady = false

func startUpCentralManager()
{
    print("Initializing central manager")
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
}

func discoverDevices()
{
    print("discovering devices")
    centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber)
{
    print("Discovered \(peripheral)")

    if (peripheral.name == "rpi")
    {
        self.remotePeripheral = peripheral
        self.centralManager.stopScan()
        self.remotePeripheral?.delegate = self
        centralManager.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager)
{
    print("checking state")
    switch (central.state)
    {
    case .PoweredOff:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off")
        bluetoothReady = false

    case .PoweredOn:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready")
        bluetoothReady = true;

    case .Resetting:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is resetting")

    case .Unauthorized:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized")

    case .Unknown:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");

    case .Unsupported:
        print("CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");

    }
    if bluetoothReady
    {
        discoverDevices()
    }
}
```

The `didDiscoverPeripheral` method always finds the same Peripheral :

```
Discovered <CBPeripheral: 0x6080000aada0 identifier = 36844111-01E4-4D00-926B-AAF089C04305, Name = "(null)", state = disconnected>
```

It's good pointing out the fact that I have exactly the same problem with the same implementation on an iOS app ( using iPhone 5 ).

Comment: While it hasn't a name, don't connect to it. The informations are gathered by piece. Maybe check also the option `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey`, and are you sure your 3 devices are Bluetooth Low-Energy?

Comment: Yes you were right, my Raspberry Pi is not BLE. Next time, I'll think a bit more before posting a question... Thanks !

Comment: It's ok to connect to a BLE device that doesn't have a name, the name can be obtained lated via `- peripheralDidUpdateName:` callback in `CBPeripheralDelegate`.

Comment: Yes but then how can I know that it is the right peripheral I'm trying to connect to ?